# Place Autocomplete is not working with google translation

Tags: php, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Place Autocomplete and it is working fine in firefox but it is not working in google chrome with translation. Our website is in arabic.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&libraries=places"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
```

Some time working and some time not working in chrome with translation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide more details? Like what did you input on your request? And what did you mean by translation? The default browser's translation? The community would greatly appreciate it if. 1. You provide your sample request or a [minimal reproducible example]() which shows the issue, 2. Your expected result/behavior.

Comment: If the issue happens when asking the Chrome browsers to translate the entire website, please report the issue to Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry